# Write text to log file Columns

Tags: vb.net, file-writing

How do I write to the columns in a .log file?
I.e there are columns for "Log Text","Component","Date/Time"

How do I specify these when writing to a file?

I've got half of it working:

```
dim str As String ="<![LOG[" & message & "]LOG]!><time=""" & Now.ToLongTimeString & """" & " date=""" & Now.ToShortDateString & """ component=""" & component.ToString & """" & " type=""1""" & " Thread=""" & t & """" & ">"
File.AppendAllText(logfile, str & vbCrLf)
```

But the component, date / time and thread values arent displaying properly.
What am I missing ?

*edited

The file path is "C:\Programdata\server.log"

So some of the text is getting into it in the right place, just not all of it.
So the log text column will get populated with "message" and thread comes in with the number but the date/time and component are empty.
I'd attach a pic but i dont have enough rep :/

In a sentance, Im trying to replicate this:
http://www.jetico.com/web_help/bcwipe6_enterprise/img/log_viewer.jpg
but not all of my columns are displaying data.

Comment: You are writing a text file. Text files don't have columns. If you pad each item with enough blanks so they contain the same number of characters, and then display the text using a fixed space font, the items will line up. Or you could delimit the items (for example with commas) and use the delimiters to split the items when you display them in something that supports columns.

Comment: edited with better description

Comment: if you use string.format it will be a lot clearer

Comment: Can you post  little of the txt file you want to create? The link shows how the data is displayed when its been read in, not how the data looks while its stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

This is to do with the format of the data I was trying to write.

Time has to be in the format
Now.ToLongTimeString & "." & Now.Millisecond & "-60"

and date has to be seperated with - instead of /

Dunno why - when viewed the time doesnt go to that length and the date is displayed with "/"

The viewer im using for the log was cmtrace.

This was the line that got it working was ..

```
<![LOG[" & message & "]LOG]!><time=""" & Now.ToLongTimeString & "." & Now.Millisecond & "-60" & """" & " date=""" & d & """ component=""" & component.ToString & """" & " type=""1" & """ Thread=""" & t &""">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try dividing your data into columns using commas as suggested by @Blackwood, but use string.format as you seem to have lots of extra "" in there

```
        Dim str As String = String.Format("![LOG[{0}]LOG]!,time={1},  <date= {2}, component= {3},  type=1, Thread={4}", Message, Now.ToLongTimeString, Now.ToLongDateString, component.ToString, t)
```

File.AppendAllText(logfile, Str() & vbCrLf)

I'm not sure what you are doing with the <> tags.